# ROS Answers SE migration: roscore error

Tags: ros, roslaunch, roscore, rosversion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have searched but have not found anything that adequately solves my problem.
When I type in "roscore" to test ros and make sure my installation was successful it displays this error:

```
roscore invalid <param>  tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1] 
Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>
```

Any help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133681/roscore-error/) by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-26**:
What is your OS and ROS version? Have you installed from binaries or from source?

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-02-26**:
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS version hydro

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-26**:
What do you get if you run `rosversion roslaunch` manually?

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-03-03**:
It says "Cannot locate [roslaunch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is usually symptomatic of not having your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH set correctly.

This usually happens if you either:

- Haven't sourced /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash **or**
- You've overwritten your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH instead of appending to it

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-03-03**:
how would i go about checking for these issues?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-03**:
What do you get for   env | grep ROS?

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-03-03**:
This is what I got:

ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros...
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/forklift/forklift-workspace:ROS_PACKAGE_PATH...
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311...
ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost...
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=...
ROS_DISTRO=hydro...
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros...

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-03**:
Please update your question with this so it's readable. The exact output is important. Is there a literal "ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-03-10**:
I appreciate your help! Your last comment gave me a thought and so I went to check the path and discovered that I had removed that file so ROS was searching for something that didn't exist. I checked with it in and its been working!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this same problem when one of my package.xml files had a parsing error. The package was in my catkin_ws which was on my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [vmlane](https://answers.ros.org/users/25474/vmlane/) with karma: 11 on 2016-01-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mateen](https://answers.ros.org/users/63708/mateen/) on 2020-11-23**:
Hi !!! How did you resolve this issue than?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I met this error when I have a grammar error in package.xml. When I correct the error, roscore and catkin_make can work.

---

Originally posted by [Amos](https://answers.ros.org/users/34051/amos/) with karma: 21 on 2018-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2